# Emacs: how to choose good custom key bindings?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I'm an Emacs beginner and I'd like to start adding some global custom key bindings for common tasks like `replace-string`, `replace-regex`, etc. that don't have them by default. I want to make good choices, and I see a few issues:

- **See all my options** - How can I see the full range of keys that are unbound across all the modes that I regularly use?
- **Compatibility/convention** - Are there common unofficial bindings or a common "user-space" key with which to begin personal custom bindings?
- **Other issues** - Anything else I should be taking into consideration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try taking a look at this question on SO: [Are there any emacs key combinations reserved for custom commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144424/are-there-any-emacs-key-combinations-reserved-for-custom-commands)

Regarding seeing what is available, there's the `unbound` library (see [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144424/are-there-any-emacs-key-combinations-reserved-for-custom-commands/1144733#1144733) to the above question).

One convention (grabbed from [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144424/are-there-any-emacs-key-combinations-reserved-for-custom-commands/1144498#1144498)) is:

You can redefine anything, but the [convention is to use](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keymaps.html#Keymaps) <kbd>C-c l</kbd> (where <kbd>l</kbd> is any letter).

> As a user, you can redefine any key;
>   but it is usually best to stick to key
>   sequences that consist of <kbd>C-c</kbd>
>   followed by a letter (upper or lower
>   case). These keys are "reserved for
>   users," so they won't conflict with
>   any properly designed Emacs extension.
>   The function keys <kbd>F5</kbd> through <kbd>F9</kbd> are also
>   reserved for users. If you redefine
>   some other key, your definition may be
>   overridden by certain extensions or
>   major modes which redefine the same
>   key.

Just remember that key bindings are different in each of the various (major and minor) modes, so what is available in one buffer isn't necessarily available in another.  And make your key bindings at the most localized level possible.  For example, if the functionality does something to a line of code, don't make a global key binding for it, define it in the appropriate keymaps (`c++-mode-map`, `ruby-mode-map`, etc.).

As far as your specific tasks, have you noticed:

- <kbd>M-%</kbd> aka `query-replace`
- <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> aka `query-replace-regexp`

Also, when you're searching (<kbd>C-s</kbd> or <kbd>C-M-s</kbd> (and the reverse variants)), you can type <kbd>M-%</kbd> (or <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>) to directly enter `query-replace` (`query-replace-regexp`) with the search string as the thing to substitute...  Pretty handy.